# Creating custom workflows for Projects

Tags: github, github-projects

I created a project for my repository and I'm trying to set up automation. Workflows allow, for example, to immediately transfer an Issue or Pull request to the desired column, for example, to ToDo.

But I want to set up different behavior, for example, transfer Issue to ToDo, and external PRs immediately to the CodeReview column. Is it possible to do this using Github?

All I see is the ability to select only the item type and one of the columns, but no more different customizations.